# Upgrading ASP.NET Core 5.0 IdentityServer4 to 6.0 error - no such table: Keys

Tags: c#, identityserver4, .net-6.0, duende-identity-server

After upgrading ASP.NET Core 5.0 with IdentityServer4 to 6.0 error - no such table: Keys

```
14:50:02.0033786|Failed executing DbCommand (4ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
SELECT "k"."Id", "k"."Algorithm", "k"."Created", "k"."Data", "k"."DataProtected", "k"."IsX509Certificate", "k"."Use", "k"."Version"
FROM "Keys" AS "k"
WHERE "k"."Use" = 'signing'
14:50:02.0179085|An exception occurred while iterating over the results of a query for context type 'xx.com.Data.AppDbContext'.
Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException (0x80004005): SQLite Error 1: 'no such table: Keys'.
```

I cant find any doc on migration from .net 5 to 6 for IdentityServer

**EDIT** *when you upgrade ID4 from .NET Core 5 to 6 it becomes Duende Server. There is no ID4 for .NET 6..*

Comment: I'm afraid there are no enough details here to answer you

Comment: Ok, thank you for details. So if you want to upgrade IS4 to Duende you can find migration guide [here](https://docs.duendesoftware.com/identityserver/v5/upgrades/is4_v4_to_dis_v5/). And yes, they mention `Keys` table there. Anyway, Duende IdentityServer is a commercial product, so I believe it's better to ask their support team

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick way to resolve this (sqlite):

```
CREATE TABLE Keys (
    Id                TEXT    NOT NULL
                              CONSTRAINT PK_Keys PRIMARY KEY,
    Version           INTEGER NOT NULL,
    Created           TEXT    NOT NULL,
    Use               TEXT,
    Algorithm         TEXT    NOT NULL,
    IsX509Certificate INTEGER NOT NULL,
    DataProtected     INTEGER NOT NULL,
    Data              TEXT    NOT NULL
);

CREATE INDEX IX_Keys_Use ON Keys (
    "Use"
);

CREATE INDEX sqlite_autoindex_Keys_1 ON Keys (
    Id COLLATE BINARY
);
```

Answer (score 3):

Disable the management of certificates via database (Table 'Keys' doesn't exists). You can stay loading certificates from any other available source.

```
services.AddIdentityServer(options => {
    options.KeyManagement.Enabled = false;
})
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: disabling a feature of a server responsible for security isnt a good idea most of the time unless you know what you are doing. But if I knew what I am doing why would I be asking trivial questions on SO ? yeah?

Answer (score 1):

Here's the correct schema for the Keys table

```sql
CREATE TABLE Keys (
    Id                nvarchar(450)    NOT NULL CONSTRAINT PK_Keys PRIMARY KEY,
    Version           INTEGER NOT NULL,
    Created           datetime2    NOT NULL,
    [Use]               nvarchar(450),
    Algorithm         nvarchar(100)    NOT NULL,
    IsX509Certificate INTEGER NOT NULL,
    DataProtected     INTEGER NOT NULL,
    Data              nvarchar(Max)    NOT NULL
);

CREATE INDEX IX_Keys_Use ON Keys (
    [Use]
);

CREATE INDEX sqlite_autoindex_Keys_1 ON Keys (
    Id 
);
```

Comment: This is for sql server. My answer is for sqlite.

Comment: Thanks! I wish this was on the documentation upgrade section for Duende!